# AngularJS datetime format get wrong hour and minute value based on localization

Tags: angularjs, datetime, angularjs-filter

I have datetime value on database as follow

[image]

But following angularJS code display wrong hour in View

```
   <i   title="Baxıldı {{item.ViewedDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss Z'}}"></i>
```

for example:

[image]

I think this error depends on localization, in my country is UTC+4, so 4 hours added to current value.

Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `timezone` as the third argument when you're using the `date` filter.

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

Here's an example if the dates in your database in stored in UTC.

```
<i   title="Baxıldı {{item.ViewedDate | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss Z': 'utc'}}"></i>
```

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date):

> Timezone to be used for formatting. It understands UTC/GMT and the
>   continental US time zone abbreviations, but for general use, use a
>   time zone offset, for example, '+0430' (4 hours, 30 minutes east of
>   the Greenwich meridian) If not specified, the timezone of the browser
>   will be used.